# Beware it's April fools day and we have unicoins

Tags: discussion

You'll probably notice this little image on the right sidebar.

[image: ss #1]

If you click it you can buy things in the unicoin store.

[image: ss #2]

The store.

[image: ss #3]

[image: ss #4]

This is just a gag, for the day (April 1st). Do not be alarmed...

#### References

- [What are Stack Overflow unicoins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227363/what-are-stack-overflow-unicoins)

Comment: With the new _max rep upgrade_ for 90 points and using 10x scale, I now have enough rep to make those 500 points bounties like I always wanted ;-)

Comment: Interesting, I actually downloaded that very image and was playing with a for an ImageMagick question. Never followed the link though, shows how much attention I pay to ads!

Answer (score 1):

Tch. Obviously a shameless marketing tie-in...

[image]

...Or else...

Adult Swim will destroy Stack Exchange in patent court over the association:

- Unicorns, okay, public domain.
- Rainbows, okay again -- public domain.

But **unicorns + rainbows** == infringement.  Everyone delete your account now before you become a liable party.

Comment: downvoted because Flash.

Comment: @strugee Lol I don't know, I've only played the Android version. It's a pretty stupid game IMO. *Giant Boulder of Death*, OTOH, quickly joined the ranks of *Galaga*, *Chopper Command*, *Doom*, and *Civilization* as responsible for some of my all time fav gaming experiences.   I'm not much for video games generally because I prefer to waste my time in online forums related to "unix and linux"...

Comment: a forum?? this is a _forum_ to you??? the very thing Stack Exchange set out to fix???? some people... :P

Answer (score 1):

Just when I think that this site has gotten 20% cooler.
[image: Frustrated]